# how to click on sidebar in automated test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Here is the script in the application

[image]
I have tried different type of locators to click on the side bard such as xpath and linktext but it does not work.
Does anybody know how to deal with this.

Comment: Can you post the solutions you tried? Both xpath and linkText should be fine.

Comment: Here is what I have tried
'element(by.css('a[href="#/pages/frontend?node=C04&key=25"]')).click();'
'element(by.xpath("//span[. = 'frontend']")).click();'
'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ion-android-home']")).click();'
'element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'frontend')).click();'

I'm not experience, so errors are expected.

Comment: I have also tried the csscontainingtext with only css, but no luck

Comment: What error(s) were you getting?

Comment: For all,its the same ,it says cannot find this locator or does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.al-sidebar-list-item').click();
```

(not sure what you need to click here, but this is an example.)

Here, `.` indicates class in css

Or, you can store it in a variable for later use:

```
var sideBar = $('.al-sidebar-list-item');
sideBar.click();
```

FYI `$` is a shortcut for `element(by.css())`

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$

Comment: I want to click the "frontend"

Comment: If you use my suggestion, it will click on the link and redirect you to the url in the href.  Is that your goal?

Comment: No, I have not tested as we got some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add implicit time out

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Further add

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

before the line where facing issue.